# Erratic behavior of editor.action.clipboardPasteAction

Tags: vscode-extensions

Since 2019 I've had a small vscode extension that just does:

```
async function pasteLines(editor: vscode.TextEditor) {
    let cur = editor.selection.active.with();
    let line = cur.with(undefined, 0);

    editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(line, line)];
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.clipboardPasteAction");
    editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(cur, cur)];
}
```

Bound to a key. It has worked great. All it does is move the cursor to the start of the line, do paste, then put the cursor back where it started.

But since Jun 2023 my snap auto-updated and this is no longer working reliably. The keybinding acts like the keyboard is broken. 5/10 presses work fine, and 5 just do nothing. Randomly. Sometimes it works entirely fine. It is like some odd race condition. Primarily testing on C language files with clang extension, but disabling extensions didn't make any difference.

Is something wrong with the Javascript?

Reverting to 1.78.2 makes it work, 1.80 does not - so it seems to be some change in vscode.
(specifcally snaps code-stable-x64-1683731562.snap is good, code-stable-x64-1686735002.snap is bad)

Removing the last `editor.selections =` seems to make it work reliably, although it does not behave as I'd like.

editor.action.clipboardPasteAction works fine on its own without the wrapper.

Comment: Your function works every time for me, calling it like so: `await pasteLines(vscode.window.activeTextEditor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, your code seems to work for me but one thing looks like it could be an issue:

```js
let line = cur.with(undefined, 0);
```

The signature for `Position.with()` is

```
with(line?: number, character?: number): Position
```

You put `undefined` in for the optional `line` when it is expecting a `number` if used.  Since that could be an issue I just eliminated that call altogether in the following code:

```js
async function pasteLines(editor) {
    // let cur = editor.selection.active.with();  // what does with() add here?
    let cur = editor.selection.active;

    // let line = cur.with(undefined, 0);
    let line = new vscode.Position(cur.line, 0);

    editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(line, line)];
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.clipboardPasteAction");
    editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(cur, cur)];
}
```

Try that and see if works consistently.

---

Does the following simpler version work:

```js
async function pasteLines(editor) {
    let cur = editor.selection.active;

    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorHome");
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.clipboardPasteAction");
    editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(cur, cur)];
}
```

---

Another try with no setting of selections. The `editor.edit` call automatically preserves the cursor position.  So that if your start with `hello | world` (cursor at `|`) and insert something in front of it, you would end up with:

```
clipboard stuff hello | world
```

```js
let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.createFile', async (args) => {

  await pasteLines(vscode.window.activeTextEditor);
}


async function pasteLines(editor) {

    let lineStart = new vscode.Position(editor.selection.active.line, 0);
    const clipboard = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText();

    editor.edit(editBuilder => editBuilder.insert(lineStart, clipboard));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck it behaves the same. When it does nothing I can see the cursor move around ever so briefly so it is like the paste just doesn't execute. I'm calling it through a vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand() as part of a tiny extension.

I'm no wizard at javascript, but undefined acts the same as omitting the positional parameter which the with() implementation handles by defaulting to the internal value.

Comment: I added a simpler version to the answer.  Since I can't reproduce the issue, I am not sure it has anything to do with this code.

Comment: Same problem with the 2nd version, it really is something about assigning editor.selections. Interestingly I also cannot make this happen from a "Extension Development Host" window, it only happens in an installed extension on a normal vscode... (with all other extensions disabled).

Comment: Where is the cursor supposed to end up?  Potentially in the pasted content?  Or in the old text where it was?

Comment: Old text where it was

Comment: I added a method which doesn't use `editor.selections = []` or clipbaord paste.  The cursor position within the previous text is preserved.

Comment: The editBuilder version does exactly what I want (with a active.line+1). Mysterious why the other versions don't work, but edit feels like a pretty robust choice going forward! Thanks!

Comment: I think it may be related to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190831#issuecomment-1692949022  I'll keep an eye on it, perhaps something changed with the async nature of pastes in vscode.